# htaccess, use site domain, but see the content of an external URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have built a shop in Wordpress but would like to include this on my website without changing the url.

Can anyone tell me why the following isn't working?

This code is in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/shop/
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.wordpress.com/shop/$1 [P]
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

@idm! Hi! Try adding the following 2 lines to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Your WordPress htaccess file should look like the following with the included 2 lines from above:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Additionally, make sure to adjust and save the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) accordingly to have https in the url's within the WordPress Shop Dashboard -> Settings -> General.

I hope that helps!

Best Regards.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. The url redirects to the shop, I want my website url including the shop I have set up on wordpress. So my URL (example.com/shop/) showing content from a different url (wordpress.com/shop/)... Is this something you can help with?